# Upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Failed

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, upgrade

I just tried to update to Ubuntu 14.04.5 on my Dell Inspiron 8600 running Ubuntu 12.02 LTS, and I received an error saying that PAE is not enabled. I looked at the support for enabling PAE on Pentium M systems, but when I tried to run the command 
`apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae` , I received an error saying:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I've tried to find answers to this in the forum, however I cannot find the solution to this. Is there any way to fix this issue? Do I need to run this as a superuser?

Comment: Yes, you need to run it as `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

The "Permission denied" error and the "are you root?" message mean you don't have permission to do Apt installs, since you need to run the program as the `root` user.

You do that by using `sudo` in front of `apt-get`, as in:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-pae
```